# ModifyPropertyFilter change property value based on the value of other property

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am using a connector and want to use `ModifyPropertyFilter` to change the value of a property based on the value of another property.

Let say I have metadata name/value as: `MockingType=someMockingValue` and `google:title=title of doc`. How can I change `google:title=new value` if `MockingType` has value of `mockingToBeReplace`?

Or please suggest another way to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to acomplish this in connector but you can achieve this with the help of frontend.
Add new value in a seperate metadata (let's say mockTitle) and also add mockingtype as seperate metadata.
And in the frontend check if mockingtype==mockingToBeReplace, if true get the mockTitle and display it as title else display google:title (default).

Comment: in 3.2 connectors you can create filters and in 4.0 connectors you can create transformers.  These allow transformations to metadata before sending the content to the GSA.  Point of clarity though...google:title does not specify the actual document title.  GSA ignores it when choosing a title.

Comment: Thank you.  That was what I did.  I used Document Filter to skip it.